# JS scroll to center with flex reverse

Tags: javascript, html, flexbox

Hi intresting moment which i didnt find in google.

How i can scroll to vertical center with flex reverse ?

Problem in example:

i have **temp1.scrollHeight = 1000**

but in top position of scroll property **temp1.scrollTop** return
'-940' (not -1000)

i think it calculate how **scrollHeight**-minus scrollbar element height:

[image]

How i can center scroll?
like:  `scrollHeight / 2 - (hight if scrollbar element / 2);`

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: i havent code i dont know how it do . i try mydiv.scrollTo(0, mydiv.scrollHeight / 2); but get not center because of the reason described above

Comment: without flex reverse - yes its variant work mydiv.scrollTo(0, mydiv.scrollHeight / 2);

Answer (score 0):

Find this API in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Element.scrollIntoView(scrollIntoViewOptions)

params:
scrollIntoViewOptions = {
block: 'center',
}
// vertical alignment center

Comment: i need scrollto center internal my div with scroll. Not view window of browser to center my div with scroll